# Verificar si existe un campo dentro de un Json

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, isset

tengo un problema con mi Json, verán, hago una consulta a la base de datos para verificar si un Paciente tiene alguna derivación o no. En caso de que la tenga, deberá devolverme los datos del paciente y además los datos de la derivación. Y, si por el contrario no cuenta con una derivación, solo me devolverá los datos de mi paciente.
Esto me lo devuelve como un Json.

Lo que quiero hacer es verificar si ese Json tiene un campo llamado, por ejemplo *nameDoctor* ya que si lo tiene, mostrara una tarjeta de datos diferente, que incluirá obviamente los datos de la derivación.

```
let patientData =  JSON.parse(this.responseText);

if(isset(patientData.nameDoctor)){
    alert('Si tiene Medico');
}else{
    alert('No tiene Medico');
}
```

Algo así. Obviamente el isset es de PHP, lo que quiero es traducir eso a JS

Comment: Puedes poner un json de ejemplo??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes preguntar si un objeto tiene una propiedad específica con el método `hasOwnProperty('propiedad')` que devuelve `true` o `false` dependiendo si el objeto tiene o no la propiedad.

```js
const obj1 = {nameDoctor: "Juan Antonio"}
const obj2 = {name: "Alberto"}

console.log(obj1.hasOwnProperty('nameDoctor'))
console.log(obj2.hasOwnProperty('nameDoctor'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Para validar si el campo existe o si es un string vacío (es decir:
`nameDoctor = ""`)
puedes usar:

```
if(patientData.nameDoctor) {
   alert('Si tiene Medico');
}
```

por otro lado si quieres algo más estructurado puedes usar isEmpty() de lodash

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEmpty

esta librería es bastante útil al momento de trabajar con objetos Json complejos

Answer (score 1):

Se puede usar `.hasOwnProperty` como han dicho, o el operador `in`, pero cada método tiene sus cosas. `.hasOwnProperty` no verifica las propiedades heredadas, lo que lo hace en general mas seguro, pero al mismo tiempo pueden pasar cosas como que lo siguiente sea `true`:

```js
[1,2,3].hasOwnProperty("length");
```

Por otro lado, el operador `in` solo funciona con objetos literales. Si controlamos la definición del objeto podemos usar tranquilamente `in`, sino, como en el caso de trabajar con objetos del dom por ejemplo, u objetos que no sabemos de que heredan, es preferible `.hasOwnProperty`. Ejemplo de `in`:

```js
const json = '{"prop":"val","nameDoctor":"Algo"}';

if ("nameDoctor" in JSON.parse(json)) {

  console.log("tiene la propiedad");

} else {

  console.log("no tiene la propiedad");

}
```

Como curiosidad, el método [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) puede recibir una especie de callback, que se llama "reviver" en verdad, dentro del "reviver" podemeos también verificar si existe la propiedad, aunque es muy poco práctico:

```js
const json = '{"prop":"val","nameDoctor":"Algo"}';

JSON.parse(json, (k) => {

  if (k === "nameDoctor") {

    console.log("tiene la propiedad");

  }

});
```